# Use netcat and write to stdin for remote shell

Tags: linux, perl, unix, stack-overflow, netcat

I am exploiting a buffer overflow vulnerability (for university) on a running server and I am able to redirect the process to exec a shell. 
My exploit looks like this:

```
perl -e 'print "\xaa\xaa\..."' | nc -q0 machineAtUni 1234
```

So the server reads from the socket, eip will be overwritten and a shell executed. The problem is that I see some message from the shell but I can't insert anything. I think that the shell itself reads from stdin till EOF but how can I achieve that I can send commands to it (that the connection stays open and I am able to write to stdin)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`netcat`'s stdin is connected to the pipe, not your terminal, so it's not sending anything you type. You can do:

```
{ perl -e 'print "\xaa\xaa\..."'; cat; } | nc -q0 machineAtUni 1234
```

so that when the perl script finishes, `cat` will read from the terminal and write to the pipe.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and quick response!